# How to clean up mesh after using Knife Project on a curved surface

Tags: modeling

How can I clean up this Knife Project operation so the bad shading disappears?

The edges created by the Knife Project operation will be used to create a hole in the mesh using the Inset operation.

[image: enter image description here]]

[image]

Comment: The cut seems to have an impact on the (future) hole part. So, try to make the hole (inset). That can also give you the ability to add more vertices along the mirror axis. But to help you more concretely, you should upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score -2):

try to make a strait line as on the pictur it shuld atleast look better.
[image]

if you whant to kep the shape add a new edge close to it and work whith it insted.
[image]

the last thing I whant to say is if you combinde the subsurfes and mirror modefiers. Put the mirror modefier firs if you don't whant a sharp edge on the mirror point.

Comment: Don't you thing that the curve, as it is in the question, is a will ?

Comment: My answer is not spesific for you'r case and it shuld solv you'r problem if you edit the shape